# where can I download the assembly MPF.Project.NonShipping.dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll

I want to use HierarchyNode class which is in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package namespace and the assembly is MPF.Project.NonShipping.dll.
There was no assembly on the .net reference or on the COM.
I searched for the file, but it was not on the machine.
I also tried to google the dll if we could download it, but there was no link, whatsoever about the download.

I am using VS 2008 sp1 by the way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the VS SDK for those.